# HSV values for thresholding white, black and grey pixels

Tags: python, image, image-processing, python-imaging-library

I have some images of plots and I am trying to find out "colorful pixels" from them. I have converted the images to HSV space. Is there any threshold for determining visually black, white and grey pixels? Something like saturation < 10% and value < 20% implies the pixel is black?

Comment: This is pretty context dependent. Play with the thresholds a bit until the results look like what you want....

Comment: The thresholds are very heuristic.  It also depends on the types of images you're using.